# Let's get critical: Feb 2013 Site Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics - Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1):

The results of the evaluation (click for larger image):

[image]

If anyone's interested in producing a better graph, here's the [actual data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Asxpisj1_dzYdHNBbkVSQ2dnaUlrOGk2SFRZZlBEMlE&single=true&gid=0&output=html).

Comment: This seems a strange way to measure to be honest... you seem to be discounting "Satisfactory", and then subtracting "Needs Improvement" from "Excellent". But at least as far as my own voting patterns in evaluation, this is calibrated Way Wrong. I only marked something as "Excellent" when it was truly outstanding, and "Needs Improvement" when it could use improvement, even if it was a good answer overall, and "Satisfactory" when it was a good answer better than anywhere on internet but not "WOW! Super!" kind. Could be that I misunderstood evaluation requirements, of course :)

Comment: @DVK I'm not doing anything, this is how SE measures the votes.

Comment: sorry, shouldn't have used "you" - I suspected it was SE's standard but wasn't sure because of the use of GoogleDocs and not SE backend. My concern stands, however, that there's a strong downward bias in grading. I'm sure I'm not the only one who used fairly strong quality standards when voting on evaluation.

Comment: @DVK Currently, the stats are mod only. That doesn't make much sense and there are already plans for the stats to be automatically posted on Meta starting with the next evaluation. But for this evaluation, this is as good as it gets. If you can produce a better graph or a different interpretation of the data, by all means feel free to post an answer here, that's exactly why I added a link to the actual data.

Comment: I am pretty sure that SE does not strive to be OK.  There strive is for excellence.  There is no penalty for satisfactory but no bonus score either.